# User choice wordpress gallery plugin that plays all

Tags: wordpress

Is there any free gallery plug-in in wordpress that can have videos, images and which would generate thumbnails of custom size, also the plug-in should be responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you should look at Flexslider 2;

http://flex.madebymufffin.com/examples/thumbnail-slider.html

It doesn't come as a Wordpress plugin as such but here's a link to a fairly comprehensive tutorial that helps you turn it into one;

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-slider-plugin-with-flexslider/